# How do I get access logs from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, logging

I am in the process of carrying out system reviews for some systems powered by SQL Server. IS there a way of getting the access logs to these systems databases spanning a period of 6 months starting from January 2020 to June 2020?

Is there a specific query that I can run to extract for me access logs on a given system FROM a given date TO a certain date?

Comment: What type of “access” are you looking to track?

Answer (score 0):

At least, you can create table with fields for username, date and time and information about transaction. Secondly, you should create trigger functions for your tables, function should write logs into you log table, this allow you to access your logs quite simply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my interest is that the database already exists with no Audits set up already, is there a way to get access logs from it specifying a given range.

Comment: @ShafiqLutaaya dbms usually write logs into tables, but not all users can access it, you can browse for db access privelege, you should be db admin or user with access.

Comment: @ShafiqLutaaya as for MS SQL, logs stored binary, so you should create transaction table by your own hands...

Answer (score 0):

> IS there a way of getting the access logs to these systems databases spanning a period of 6 months starting from January 2020 to June 2020?

In its default configuration SQL Server doesn't record all logins, or access to tables, and doesn't retain the information it does record indefinitely.  Look in the SQL Server log folder, eg

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log
```

And normally you'll see the SQL Logs, the Default Trace and the System Health XEvent session.  Each of these can be read with queries or by external programs.